# What is the difference between took and taken?

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between took and taken?

As an example assume a monkey is in a well, and someone is trying to say they would have taken the money out. Are both of these sentences grammatically correct?

> I would have jumped in there and took the monkey out

or

> I would have jumped in there and taken the monkey out.

Comment: There are _some dialects_ where the simple past tense and the past participle are not distinguished (except in a few verbs). In those dialects, “I have took”, “I have gave”, “I have saw”, etc. are acceptable. These dialects are a minority, however. In the vast majority of dialects, the past tense is _took/gave/saw_, the past participle is _taken/given/seen_, and only the second of your examples is grammatical.

Comment: My apologies, every over stack exchange I have used is either open to 'basic' questions or relocates them if appropriate. This said I predominately used the scientific ones, perhaps such communities are less inclined fence off access to knowledge.

Comment: Surely, even on scientific SE sites, very basic questions that can be found in any standard reference work are considered unsuitable? I have a hard time thinking that asking on [physics.se] what number oxygen has in the periodic table will gain you much. Incidentally, if you edit your question to ask for further details on _which_ dialects would consider both your examples correct, and indeed if there are differences in _how_ the conflation between past and participle forms works and how the forms are used in those dialects—then that would be a very good question for ELU.

Comment: If you asked that question on Physics it would be moved to Chemistry since it has nothing to do with Physics. Perhaps as a contrast I can recognise the spirit of a question, to which I would say standard book questions are generally answered. I am not a linguist so I didn't know how to phrase it well, I was actually hoping for a thoughtful discussion rather than a simple yes/no. The fact that I need to rephrase it in the appropriate jargon speaks to what kind of community this is.

Comment: It doesn’t have to be in the appropriate jargon. But your question was, verbatim, “What is the difference between _took_ and _taken_?” That question can be answered by looking in any dictionary. Thoughtful discussions are not what SE sites are for: they’re for authoritative answers (which often engender some discussion, but that’s a by-product), and authoritative answers require at least somewhat precise questions. From your later comments, it seems you’re a native English speaker, which means you are perfectly well aware of the difference between those two words; but that’s [cont’d-->]

Comment: [-->cont’d] not obvious from your question alone. We get quite a lot of questions here that really are just “what does this word mean?” or “is this grammatically correct?”, with no further thought, and those are just clutter. A simple, non-jargon way of asking what I think you’re asking: “As a native speaker of English, I might say, _I would have taken X_; but I’ve heard presumably native speakers say things like _I would have took X_, which sounds bizarre to me. What’s going on? Is this grammatically correct somewhere? Is it just dialects?”

Comment: (And yes, of course I meant [chemistry.se], not [physics.se]. Brainfart.)

Comment: That mostly fair, more context is probably needed for language based questions. I guess in science simple questions can have deep explanations, some of the most popular questions have been one line that a high school kid could 'answer', but people have responded with paragraphs of thoughtful reasoning. The problem with my question and perhaps grammar in general is that it is essential arbitrary thus it was foolish to hope for a deep reply. Yes SE should have authoritative answers, discussion was a poor choice of word, thoughtful reasoning is what I should have said.

Comment: That’s the thing, though—subjects like physics and chemistry seem “essentially arbitrary” to someone like me, whereas language and grammar, to a large extent, are full of systems and regularities. But yes, they always rely heavily on context, which is always king here on ELU. But it can be hard to think inside someone else’s box. :-]

Comment: Whether the laws of Physics are arbitrary is an active area of research. For arguments sake lets say they are, then the point of arbitrariness is on a far different scale to grammer. Anyway thanks for the helpful pointers about how to phrase questions on ELU, should I ever dare enter these waters again.

Comment: @User You say 'I am not a linguist so I didn't know how to phrase it well'. But ELU is intended for linguists, as is made clear in the introductory tour. Should universities be required to take people who haven't achieved GCSEs? Would one accuse them of being elitist if they refused to? There are other sites intended for more basic questions, some very good. Does ELU have to become a clone?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth ELU doesn't have to do anything, but I am still allowed to give my opinion. Universities are a very poor example as most professors are happy to take genuine questions from the public. They certainly don’t claim it is rude to have asked them a question if they have not done the GCSEs. Even if we accept the presume that basic questions should be closed so as not to waste the time of its membership, to criticise someone for choosing to take the time to help educate someone is contemptuous and elitist.

Comment: Universities are a good example. You wouldn't be allowed in a lecture or tutorial unless you were qualified. Plenty of the people who answer  questions here are happy to answer basic questions on English. Elsewhere. We've had people asking questions about maths here. Even someone asking about how to keep goldfish healthy. They're trying to dictate that the site should be run the way they want.

Comment: The core issue you raise is that requiring qualifications for receiving an education is not always elitist, and your proof is that university admission restrictions are not elitist. The logical problem with this is that by choosing another form of education such as questions on a website, your statement now says nothing as to whether they are elitist. For the statement to be relevant you would have to claim requiring qualifications for education is never elitist,  putting aside the problem with proof by example, it is trivial to come up with a counter example which falsifies this statement.

Comment: The up shot of all this is that conflating education generally with the ability to ask questions gives you logically floored conclusions. There are clear and obvious restrictions on the number of students a university can take and thus restricting their number is not particularly elitist. If however wikipedia restricted access to those with an IQ above 100 I would consider it elitist as bandwidth costs and moderation time are not clear limits. I think it is reasonable for SE to be somewhere in between, for the most part SE does but I would argue ULE's balance is not consistent with other SEs.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth So the degree to which basic questions are unnecessarily closed I would say that it is elitist, but most SEs get this right and in truth ELU is probably not too far off the mark, thus this is not my issue. What I do however fail to see any reasonable justification for is criticising people whom choose to answer a question which may be closed in the future, this is primarily what I found distasteful. And your comment that is rude to ask an honest question which wastes your time is unequivocally elitist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Took is the *simple past tense*, whereas taken is the *past participle*.

This means that you can say took on its own, e.g.

> I **took** the cake,

but you have to have an auxiliary (helping) verb with taken, e.g.

> I **have** taken

---

In your case the **second** example is correct, as your verb is in the conditional perfect which requires an auxilliary ('having' in this case,) therefore the past participle (taken) is necessary.

Also, not only is

> I would have jumped in there and took the monkey out

gramatically incorrect, it sounds wrong as well.

See http://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/lessons/simple-past-or-past-participle for more information on the difference between the **past tense** and the **past participle**

Comment: Hello. Jofish. This question is too basic for ELU.

Comment: Sorry? I don't understand... I didn't ask the question... @EdwinAshworth

Comment: It shouldn't be answered.

Comment: Okay, just trying to help. Not sure what I can do about this just answering the person's question. @EdwinAshworth

Comment: Have you done the Help Center tour and had a look on Meta? '... we write stuff in comments that is too obvious to qualify for an answer. [ELU is] a site for linguists and etymologists ...' RegDwigнt' // Is: Are both of these sentences grammatically correct? : 'I would have jumped in there and took the monkey out' ... a question a linguist would be expected to ask? There are many other sites devoted to basic English. This site is devoted to less basic questions.

Comment: @Jofish Thanks for taking the time to write a response.

Comment: @User If only more people would be as polite about sticking to ELU's requirements for asking questions!

Comment: @EdwinAshworth If only people were polite about why a question is outside the requirements, then this SE would be less toxic.

Comment: Ooh, fight, fight, fi-... Ok I'll be sensible. Whilst perhaps @EdwinAshworth has a point about the type of questions we are looking to field on the site, I think that it was a genuine mistake/oversight on user's part and that really s/he couldn't have been much more polite about it. He was just looking for an answer to his question (and isn't that what this site is *really* about?) And by the way user your thank you was appreciated you are very welcome :)

Answer (score -4):

Taken is the *past participle* and hence is grammatically correct in your sentence using the comditional perfect. Took is the *simple past* and is not used with auxiliary verbs.

Comment: Did you accidentally turn off auto-correct? (Additionally, as Edwin mentioned in his comments above, this question does not belong on ELU at all, and therefore it is better to refrain from answering it here.)